# Why sometimes people prefer strtoll to strtol even they only want to convert a string to an int32?

Tags: c++, gflags

Here is the code snippet I read from google's gflags source code

```
case FV_INT32: {
  const int64 r = strto64(value, &end, base);
  if (errno || end != value + strlen(value))  return false;  // bad parse
  if (static_cast<int32>(r) != r)  // worked, but number out of range
    return false;
  SET_VALUE_AS(int32, static_cast<int32>(r));
  return true;
}
```

and the macros define strto64

```
// Work properly if either strtoll or strtoq is on this system
#ifdef HAVE_STRTOLL
# define strto64  strtoll
# define strtou64  strtoull
#elif HAVE_STRTOQ
# define strto64  strtoq
# define strtou64  strtouq
#else
// Neither strtoll nor strtoq are defined.  I hope strtol works!
# define strto64 strtol
# define strtou64 strtoul
#endif
```

Clearly, the author prefer strtoll to strtol. According the man page of these two functions, 
 one returns *long long int*, and the other returns *long int*. They are all ok if you only want an int32, right?

So what's the difference between those two functions? Why strtoll is preferred?

Comment: It is used in range. If we use an integer of 32 bit then we have ran out of range when we try to store a mobile number, If we use long long int the range exceeds than previous so that we can store more numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually: "whys is `strto64` used here when the flag is `FV_INT32` ?":

This code seems to prefer `strto64` because of this check:

```
if (static_cast<int32>(r) != r)
```

So it first tries to gulp as much as possible of the number, hence `strto64`. After it has that it can comfortably check it that fits in 32 bits.

---

About `strtoll`: `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide. So it makes sense to prefer it for `strto64`.

Comment: But you only want an int32, right? You can gulp a _long long int_, but finally you will cast it into an int32. If the number is larger than int32, it still returns false. So a _long int_ seems suffice.

Comment: @coinsyx A `long int` isn't guaranteed to be 64 bits, like a `long long` is.

Answer (score 0):

On systems that support `long long int`, it's at least a 64 bit integer. On the other hand, the guarantee for `long int` is that it is at least a 32 bit integer. On some systems / with some compilers, `long int` is a 64 bit integer. On others, it's only 32 bits. The Google header is hoping that a `long int` is indeed 64 bits on systems that don't provide `strtoll` or `strtoq` because otherwise there is no way to convert a string to a `long long int`.